# Someone is using my IP address and changing things

Tags: ip

It looks as if someone is using my IP address, going into one of my work programs and changing things.  How can I research this and see who it is?

Comment: Are "work programs" at some type of business or corporation, where you could talk to someone in charge at the IT department and have them investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to provide us with more details about "what things" are being changed, and how your network is set up - its almost impossible to answer your question based on the scant information you have provided.

Assuming - and its a big assumption - that your work programs are located "in the cloud" - ie not on your premises, and that everyone at work is behind the same connection is presenting the same IP addres it makes it highly likely that the person who is "going in and changing things" is on your network.

I guess you can either change your password to protect yourself or you can start intercepting the traffic and then tracking it down - this would need to be done on your LAN by a system administrator who has access to the router (as well as a router which can support this) - its not something "any end user" can do.

Something "any end user" may be able to do is to get a list of login times and see if you can co-ordinate them with who was at work at each time and narrow things down that way.  It might also help protect you if you can demonstrate it was not you.   If you are very lucky (and your work program is actually a web browser) you may find the service provider can find the browser type which might give you more clues.

Again, absent knowing anything about your network and the work programs in question this is simply wild speculation.   (It is possible that someone could be masquerading as your computer by forcing the IP address on the LAN, but this is more likely to ring alarm bells and prevent your connection from working - it is also a much more sophisticated attack, so you would immediately suspect people with a good knowledge of networking.